# Sql between query trying to get DATETIME column and not the condition

Tags: sql, odbc, between

I'm trying to filter between two DateTimes allowing null values too

I'm using OdbcDataAdapter

```cs
objCon = new OdbcConnection(connStr05);
objDA = new OdbcDataAdapter(query, objCon);
```

The connection is working fine because I use it for another select queries.

And I'm filling a datatable with that info

```cs
DataTable objDTfinal = new DataTable();
objDA.Fill(objDTfinal);
```

I've tested different queries...

This one works (don't crash when start filling) but it crashes showing this error: 
Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime Exception

```
"SELECT * FROM DBName.PUB.gvehicu 
where (( \"GVVE-fecmat\" BETWEEN '1753-01-01' 
AND '2500-12-31' or ( \"GVVE-fecmat\" IS NULL )) 
and (( \"GVVE-finiga\" BETWEEN '1753-01-01' 
AND '2500-12-31') OR ( \"GVVE-finiga\" IS NULL )))"
```

The same query without null condition get half of the results but its working and filling it all fine.

My boss told me that when he works with dates, he uses Convert(DATETIME, value) so I tried this way too
But this query automatically throws an error that cannot find the column DATETIME

```
"SELECT * FROM DBname.PUB.gvehicu 
where (( \"GVVE-fecmat\" BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME,'1753-01-01') 
AND CONVERT(DATETIME,'2500-12-31')) or ( \"GVVE-fecmat\" IS NULL )) 
and (( \"GVVE-finiga\" BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME,'1753-01-01') 
AND CONVERT(DATETIME,'2500-12-31')) OR ( \"GVVE-finiga\" IS NULL ))"
```

```
System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: 'ERROR [42S22] [DataDirect][ODBC Progress OpenEdge Wire Protocol driver][OPENEDGE]Column "DATETIME" cannot be found or is not specified for query. (13865)'
```

I'm not sure if it should work with convert and I'm doing something wrong, or there is another way to get this.

I'm trying to get automatically all table values with one operation to fill a DataTable object that I will throw to another table with SqlBulkCopy, that's why I'm using this way to work.
The source database is a Progress that I'm accessing with odbc connection and the ending database is SQL

Comment: Which is the "ending database"? (SQL is a languange. MS SQL Server is a product.)

Comment: Yep sorry, ending database is My SQL. By the way it's throwing error filling the datatable object, before trying to use the BulkCopy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found the solution.
With progress database you have to pass the datatimes in different format.
Passing datetimes without convert and in this format worked for me: 'YYYY-mm-dd', but if you have the year, month or day into a variable you have to pass like '@YEAR@' + '-' + '@MONTH@' + '-' + '01'
Because there is a lot of information and it still crashes because timeout, I've done different ranges of datetimes to solve it.

```
SELECT * FROM AUTO05AS.PUB.rhiscab where "RHMC-fecmov" < '1900-01-01'
SELECT * FROM AUTO05AS.PUB.rhiscab where "RHMC-fecmov" < '2000' + '-' + '01' + '-' + '01' AND "RHMC-fecmov" > '1900' + '-' + '01' + '-' + '01'
SELECT * FROM AUTO05AS.PUB.rhiscab where "RHMC-fecmov" < '2010' + '-' + '01' + '-' + '01' AND "RHMC-fecmov" > '2000' + '-' + '01' + '-' + '01' 
SELECT * FROM AUTO05AS.PUB.rhiscab where "RHMC-fecmov" < '2015' + '-' + '01' + '-' + '01' AND "RHMC-fecmov" > '2010' + '-' + '01' + '-' + '01' 
SELECT * FROM AUTO05AS.PUB.rhiscab where "RHMC-fecmov" < '2020' + '-' + '01' + '-' + '01' AND "RHMC-fecmov" > '2015' + '-' + '01' + '-' + '01' 
SELECT * FROM AUTO05AS.PUB.rhiscab where "RHMC-fecmov" > '2020-01-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

From the exception it is clear that query builder is looking for "DATETIME" as column in table, which means first parameter must be value. change the query as below and try.

```
"SELECT * FROM DBname.PUB.gvehicu 
where (( \"GVVE-fecmat\" BETWEEN CONVERT('1753-01-01', DATETIME) 
AND CONVERT('2500-12-31', DATETIME)) or ( \"GVVE-fecmat\" IS NULL )) 
and (( \"GVVE-finiga\" BETWEEN CONVERT('1753-01-01' , DATETIME) 
AND CONVERT('2500-12-31', DATETIME)) OR ( \"GVVE-finiga\" IS NULL ))"
```

Comment: I've tried
```c#
"SELECT * FROM DBName.PUB.gvehicu 
where (( \"GVVE-fecmat\" BETWEEN CONVERT('1753-01-01',DATETIME) 
AND CONVERT('2500-12-31',DATETIME)) or ( \"GVVE-fecmat\" IS NULL )) 
and (( \"GVVE-finiga\" BETWEEN CONVERT('1753-01-01',DATETIME) 
AND CONVERT('2500-12-31',DATETIME)) OR ( \"GVVE-finiga\" IS NULL ))"
```
This throws the same error:
```error
System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: 'ERROR [42S22] [DataDirect][ODBC Progress OpenEdge Wire Protocol driver][OPENEDGE]Column "DATETIME" cannot be found or is not specified for query. (13865)'

```

Comment: Can you try convert to DATE in place of DATETIME. Like `CONVERT('1753-01-01',DATE)`

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM DBName.PUB.gvehicu where (( \"GVVE-fecmat\" BETWEEN CONVERT('1753-01-01',DATE) AND CONVERT('2500-12-31',DATE)) or ( \"GVVE-fecmat\" IS NULL )) and (( \"GVVE-finiga\" BETWEEN CONVERT('1753-01-01',DATE) AND CONVERT('2500-12-31',DATE)) OR ( \"GVVE-finiga\" IS NULL ))"`
ERROR: 
`System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: 'ERROR [HY000] [DataDirect][ODBC Progress OpenEdge Wire Protocol driver][OPENEDGE]Syntax error in SQL statement at or about "DATE) AND CONVERT('2500-12-31',DATE)) or" (10713)'`